# How to filter sensitive information when logging with Sinatra and Rack Logger

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, rack

I maintain a Sinatra app that acts as a JSON API service. The API is consumed by another web app, as well as a mobile app.

I'd like to have Rack::CommonLogger exclude sensitive information, like a password, from its logs. Rails has this setting enabled, but I have found no documentation how to do this in Sinatra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to intercept the call to write and filter out sensitive messages like so :

```
logger = Logger.new("my_common.log")
logger.instance_eval do
  def write(msg)
    self.send(:<<, msg) if !msg.match /SUPER SENSITIVE INFO HERE/
  end
end
```

then, configure Rack::CommonLogger to use this instance of the logger:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
```

Comment: If you're adding this snippet to config.ru, you'll need to create the new logger as ::Logger.new. (Yes, add the two colons so that you're looking for the Logger in the root namespace, not the current one.) Otherwise you'll get an instance of Rack::Logger which doesn't work (no << method, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra logs to STDERR which is an IOm but we don't want to store other peoples passwords:

```
module NoTokenLogging
  def write(*args)
    args.first.sub!(/password=\S+/, "password=[FILTERED]")
    super
  end
end
IO.prepend NoTokenLogging
```

Comment: This works in principle but will match non-space characters as well (ie, `password=FOO&user=bar` would get morphed to `password=[FILTERED]`). Along with this, this would affect if you _ever_ want to use the `IO` object to write `password=` to a stream.

Comment: To make this more generic (and the regex more correct) you can do:
`%w(token password).each { |filter_param| args.first.sub!(/#{filter_param}=\S+?\b/, "#{filter_param}=[FILTERED]") }`, but I think (for example) if I'm building a proxy that needs to send the credentials along in the same format, this would break due to the issue that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just leverage `ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter`.

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/ParameterFilter.html